# Symfony: Resolve Doctrine EntityNotFoundException

Tags: database, symfony, doctrine, dql

I have a pre-existing Oracle database that I want to exploit.

To do this, I created 2 classes that I map with many-to-one and one-to-many. But there are elements of which the first class have no correspondence in the second class, however id exists. It does not return any error.

I would like that it sends me rather a null. How to do that ?

```
class Fact
{

/**
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="present\UserBundle\Entity\March",mappedBy="fact", cascade={"persist","remove"})     
     */
    private $march;
}

class March
{
   ...

     /*
     * @var \present\PublishBundle\Entity\image
        * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="present\UserBundle\Entity\fact",inversedBy="march", cascade={"persist"}) 
      * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="id")
     * })
     * })  
     */
     private $facture;
     }
```

the error

> Entity of type 'present\UserBundle\Entity\Client' for IDs id(0) was not found

Thanx you

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your code but I think your error has to do your JoinColumn declaration :

> @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id",referencedColumnName="id")

In the documentation [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html) it says that the name attribute will define the name of the column for your relation. 
But here "id" is also referencing to your primary key I suppose.

To solve it, try to change the name="id" by name="march_id", or remove the JoinColumn.

Edit : I have read a bit to quickly the error, haven't seen it's referencing to Client entity, can you show the code related to this relation too ?

Comment: in fact, as I said above, the error is not really due to the code ... but to the database. Imagine that Client has a march_id = 0. but in the march table, there is no line with id = 0. It returns me Entity of type 'present\UserBundle\Entity\Client' for IDs id(0) was not found. I wish it would send me back a null